# AngularJS : date-time picker (vs) zoom in graph : one or the other not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my AngularJS Application, am trying to draw a graph based on the user's selection of time period (which uses a date-time picker). Screenshot below :

[image]

**WHEN USING 1.7.1**

Am using [bootstrap JS for date-time picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). The issue is that when I use JQuery version 1.7.1, the graph zoom works, but the date-time picker doesn't work. 
This is the error in the browser console :

```
Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.
    at Error (native)
    at Function.f.extend.clean (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4:4522)
    at Function.f.buildFragment (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4:2303)
    at f.fn.extend.domManip (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4:1672)
    at f.fn.extend.append (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:31818)
    at DateTimePicker.fillDate (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:9195)
    at DateTimePicker.update (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:6538)
    at DateTimePicker.init (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:2408)
    at new DateTimePicker (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:125)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:23028) <div class="input-append ng-pristine ng-valid" startdatetime="" ng-model="var1" ng-style="{'display': 'inline-block'}"> angular1.2.1.js:84
Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.
    at Error (native)
    at Function.f.extend.clean (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4:4522)
    at Function.f.buildFragment (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4:2303)
    at f.fn.extend.domManip (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:4:1672)
    at f.fn.extend.append (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js:3:31818)
    at DateTimePicker.fillDate (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:9195)
    at DateTimePicker.update (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:6538)
    at DateTimePicker.init (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:2408)
    at new DateTimePicker (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:125)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.0.103:8080/restapi/date-picker/dateTimeBootstrap.js:26:23028) <div class="input-append ng-pristine ng-valid" enddatetime="" ng-model="var1" ng-style="{'display': 'inline-block'}">
```

**WHEN USING 1.9.1**

And, when using 1.9.1, graph zoom doesn't work, but the date-time picker works. And the browser throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined jquery-ui.min.js:380
    a.widget._mouseCapturejquery-ui.min.js:380
    a.widget._mouseDownjquery-ui.min.js:26
    (anonymous function)jquery-ui.min.js:25
    b.event.dispatchjquery.js:9593
    v.handle
```

**PLUNKR CODE**

Here's the [plunkr code](http://plnkr.co/edit/0kZraJ3abSPb9IP6PK1S?p=preview).
And the JQuery script version code am referring to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *What about [jQuery 1.8](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js)*? just kidding. Do you maybe receive errors in the console? How are you using zoom?

Comment: @Spokey, thanks for pointing out that. Added now in the original post. With zoom, we are intending to zoom into a specific portion of the graph.

Comment: You need to upgrade your jQuery UI to at least version 1.9.2 to be compatible if you are using jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: thanks @Spokey ! it works! please add it as an answer so I can mark your answer right! thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are incompatibility issues when using AngularJS with jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.15 or below. 
Simply upgrade to a newer version of jQuery UI (in this case 1.9.2+) to solve the problem.